# ASP.NET precompile fails to merge a single user control

Tags: asp.net, compilation, web-deployment-project

I have  rather large third party ASP.NET WebSite project that I precompile and merge using MSBuild and the Microsoft Web Deployment targets. I don't precompile the .aspx and .ascx files, only the codefiles.

During the precompilation phase, the user control is compiled into an assembly that is not merged into the final WebSite.dll assembly. The final output contains:

- WebSite.dll
- App_Web_selectsinglepath.ascx.73690ebc.dll

All other user controls were compiled into assemblies with names like App_Web_abcdefgh.dll and these assemblies were merged into WebSIte.dll, just this one control was not.

What could be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Can you post the build output?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to use `aspnet_compile` and `aspnet_merge` from the command line for a Web App project. Two controls would always have named assemblies instead of `App_Web_[hex].dll`, then would fail to load after the merge.

In my case I was able to add the `-fixednames` flag to the `aspnet_compile` call, which generated all of the control libraries as `App_Web_[control_name].[hex].dll`, which made them all visible to `aspnet_merge`, which removed the assembly loading error.

I still don't understand why those controls would consistently be generated with a different file name pattern (no duplicate page or control names in the hierarchy), but HTH someone.

Answer (score -2):

User controls are compiled into separate assemblies because this allows you to treat your user controls as web controls.  You can use ILMerge utility to merge multiple assemblies into one.  Here is [a good page explaining this.](http://azamsharp.com/Posts/68_Different_Approaches_for_Merging_Assemblies_Together_Using_ILMerge.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I was asking.